# show the {absolute_results} only once

Tags: count

If have a channel called 'scripts' and i want to display how many entries are in the channel filtered by the categorie they are in.
For the category id 5 it should returns 4 entries. But it is displayed like 4 4 4 4. How can show the `{absolute_results}` only once?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="scripts" category="5" disable="category_fields"}
    {absolute_results}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Update** (full code):

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="scripts" style="linear"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="scripts" category="{category_id}" disable="category_fields"}
        {if absolute_results == absolute_results}
            <strong>{absolute_results}</strong>
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

The channel entries loop run 4 times so you get repeated values.

Try something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="scripts" dynamic="no" category="5"
    disable="custom_fields|categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships"
}
    {if count == total_results}
        {total_results}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Update based on question update involving categories tag pair:

You should go with query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(ct.entry_id) as ab_results FROM exp_channel_titles ct JOIN exp_category_posts cp ON cp.entry_id = ct.entry_id WHERE ct.channel_id=29 AND cp.cat_id=65"}
    {ab_results} 
{/exp:query}
```

Query module is required to run this.

Comment: That works, but I want to do this without the count because i'm setting the category_id dynamically. Im using the categories tag with the entries tag like this so my count is not equal to the absolute_results: <br/>{exp:channel:categories channel="scripts" style="linear"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="scripts"  category="{category_id}" disable="category_fields"}

 {if absolute_results == absolute_results}
    <strong>{absolute_results}</strong>
    {/if}<br/>

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}

Comment: Well in that case, Channel entries tag won't help you. You should go with query. `{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(ct.entry_id) as ab_results FROM exp_channel_titles ct JOIN exp_category_posts cp ON cp.entry_id = ct.entry_id  WHERE ct.channel_id=29 AND cp.cat_id=65"}
 {ab_results}
 {/exp:query}`  Query module required to run this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using an Add-on called Construct Categories by Buzzingpixel.